# How do I convert to Chomsky Normal Form(CNF)

Tags: chomsky-normal-form

How do I convert below grammar to CNF?

```
S → ASA | aB

A → B | S

B → b | ε
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can split the transformation of context free grammars to Chomsky Normal Form into four steps.

1. The *Bin* step ensures that all alternatives in all productions contains no more than two terminals or non-terminals.
2. The *Del* step "deletes" all empty string tokens.
3. The *Unit* steps "inlines" productions that directly map to a single non-terminal.
4. The *Term* step makes sure terminals and non-terminals are not mixed in any alternative.

From your example, describing each step, the transformation to CNF can look like the following.

#### Bin

Alternatives in production S is split up into smaller productions. New non-terminals are T.

```
S → AT | aB
A → B | S
B → b | ε
T → SA
```

#### Del

From the production of S, nullable non-terminals A and B were factored out.

```
S → AT | T | aB | a
A → B | S
B → b | ε
T → SA
```

For the production of A, no action need be taken.

```
S → AT | T | aB | a
A → B | S
B → b | ε
T → SA
```

From the production of B, empty string tokens were removed.

```
S → AT | T | aB | a
A → B | S
B → b
T → SA
```

From the production of T, nullable non-terminal A were factored out.

```
S → AT | T | aB | a
A → B | S
B → b
T → SA | S
```

#### Unit

"Inlined" the production for B in A.

```
S → AT | T | aB | a
A → b | S
B → b
T → SA | S
```

#### Term

Replaced a terminal "a" in production S with the new non-terminal U.

```
S → AT | T | UB | a
A → b | S
B → b
T → SA | S
U → a
```

And you're done.